# If $A\subseteq\overline{B}$, then $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}$? Confusion about a detail in a proof of the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

**Context:**

I'm working through a proof of the Open Mapping Theorem. The setup is as follows: suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, and $T : X\to Y$ is a surjective continuous linear operator. To prove an intermediate result, assume additionally that there is $r>0$ such that $rB(Y)\subseteq \overline{T(D(X))}$. We wish to show that $rD(Y)\subseteq T(D(X))$ (where $B(Y) = \{y\in Y\ :\ \|y\|\le 1\}$ and $D(Y) = \{y\in Y\ :\ \|y\|<1\}$.

The proof starts with a relatively innocuous first step. Let $A = T(D(X))\cap rB(Y)$. They then go on to claim that

> $\overline{A} = rB(Y)$

I can't figure out why this is true. I know that $\overline{A}\subseteq rB(Y)$. I was wondering if it's perhaps a special case of the question I posed above. If the question I asked is actually *false*, then how is it the case that $\overline{A} = rB(Y)$? Does this have something to do with the nature of the sets $rB(Y)$ and $T(D(X))$ that I'm missing?

---

This lead me to pose the following question:

> **Question:** In a topological space $(X, \tau)$ with sets $A, B\subseteq X$, $A$ closed and $A\subseteq\overline{B}$, then is $\overline{A\cap B}= A$?

As user **s.harp** pointd out, this is false in general (take $A = \mathbb{Q}$, $B = \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$).

Hence, either the proof I'm reading is wrong, or there is some additional condition on the set $A$ which allows $\overline{A} = rB(Y)$.

Comment: As a counter example to the question in your title, consider $A=\Bbb Q$ and $B=\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ as subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: There we go, brilliant. So what's the extra condition that allows $\overline{A} = rB(Y)$?

Comment: $B(Y)$ and $T(D(X))$ are very special sets. For example $T(D(X))$ is balanced, meaning you can multiply its elements by numbers in $[0,1]$ without leaving the set. As such if you have a sequence in $T(D(X))$ approximating an arbitrary point in $r\cdot B(Y)$ you can multiply the sequence by suitable numbers $c_n≤1$ with $c_n\to1$ so that everything is in $r\cdot B(Y)$ at all times without leaving $T(D(X))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\|y\|\leq r$, consider $z_{N}=(1-1/N)y$, then $\|z_{N}\|<r$. Since $rB(Y)\subseteq\overline{T(D(X))}$, choose a sequence $(y_{n})\subseteq T(D(X))$ such that $y_{n}\rightarrow z_{N}$. Now $\|y_{n}\|\leq\|y_{n}-z_{N}\|+\|z_{N}\|$. We let $\|y_{n}-z_{N}\|<r-\|z_{N}\|$ for large $n$, for these $n$, one has $\|y_{n}\|<r$, so $y_{n}\in T(D(X))\cap rB(Y)=A$ and hence $z_{N}\in\overline{A}$. But $z_{N}\rightarrow y$ and $\overline{A}$ is closed, then $y\in\overline{A}$.

Comment: This shows inclusion, but not equality. One has to use the fact that the image is dense in the ball of radius $r$ for that.

Comment: But OP has showed that $\overline{A}\subseteq rB(Y)$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I confused myself. You are correct.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't this prove $rD(Y)\subseteq \overline{A}$? I can't see how to make this proof work if $\|y\|\le r$.

Comment: I proved that $rB(Y)\subseteq\overline{A}$.

Comment: Wait a minute, your $B(Y)$ is the closed ball?

Comment: Yes $B(Y) = \{y\in Y\ :\ \|y\|\le 1\}$, and $D(Y) = \{y\in Y\ :\ \|y\|<1\}$. I'm tentatively going to undo acceptance of your answer because, unless I'm missing something, I don't think the proof as you've prevented is fixable if $\|y\|=r$.

Comment: I have fixed it, take a look.

Comment: Clever adjustment! Thanks a lot!